# Possible performance issues with huge PostgreSQL table

Tags: database, performance, postgresql

The website I'm create has "Events". Events have a title, date, and the userids of the people involved. An event can be anything from following someone, creating a new post, etc. I was thinking of storing all events in a single table, but I could see this getting very big very quickly.

Am I doing it right? When I need to search the table for, say, event pertaining to a certain user, how bad of a toll would that be on the system? Could I optimise it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would add indexes on the columns you most frequently use in WHERE clauses, e.g. if you are frequently selecting all events that pertain to a certain user, you should create an index on the user_id column.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createindex.html

Comment: This may not be a good idea. If the table is undergoes a lot of writes (and it looks like it does), then adding an index might actually slow down the overall system!

Answer (score 0):

As long as the data in that table is [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), you should be OK. If you find that read queries on that table slow down, you can add an index to some of the columns, but you should keep in mind that this will slow down writes to that table.

If you find that the performance is too slow, you can switch to using some [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) database that's better optimized for large tables.

Comment: Would you be able to give me an idea of a size of table which would start showing performance issues when reading/writing? Are we talking hundreds, thousands, hundreds of thousands of entries to see a lag?

Comment: It's hard to say without doing any measurements on your specific database and the queries you make, but I would estimate around hundreds of thousands.

Answer (score 0):

If table will be really big, you can use partitioning:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html
but you must choose a good partition key - good candidates are:

- event timestamp
- event type
- user_id

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the quantity of events. For example, we have a table with 490 m records in PostgreSQL and it starts being too heavy for building reports and executing scripts after 250-300 m records. Even indexes didn't help. So it could be a good idea splitting the table in parts choosing the type of event or the time period. Let's say one table for every year or quarter

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).